# Using base class constructor to initialize child class

Tags: c++, c++11

So I have a base class Base and a few child classes. What I want to do is have a base class constructor that creates a child class based on a string argument, like:

```
Base:Base(string class_name) {
    switch(class_name) {
        case "something":
            *this = SomeChildClass(...);
            ...
    }
}
```

This compiles and runs but the object doesn't have the characteristics of the child class and I don't understand why. Shouldn't this work?

Comment: Do some research about the *factory pattern*.

Comment: As for what's wrong with the code you currently have, do some research about *object slicing*.

Comment: This sounds like terrible design. In general a base class should know nothing about its child classes. But assuming you get this working, how would you use `Base` in your code?

Comment: The line `*this = new SomeChildClass(...);` should not compile, since the left hand side is a reference and the right hand side is a pointer.

Comment: @pschill It's all just pseudo-code in the question (but that doesn't matter here, as it shows intent clearly). cf. `:`, `switch` on string, etc.

Comment: @pschill yea you're right, new shouldn't be there.

Comment: @melpomene The idea was when reading input data I would create a different class for each string in input through the constructor of the base class.

Comment: @Ferus Why through the constructor of the base class? What would the calling code look like? Why not just use a function, like `obj = make_instance(input)`?

Comment: @melpomene Because it's a lot of hassle returning pointers from methods. Instead I could do obj = new Base(...)

Comment: @Ferus How is `obj = make_instance(input)` more hassle than `obj = new Base(input)`?

Comment: @melpomene Was some instance I had a problem with earlier, don't remember which. Maybe it's not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't do this in a *constructor,* because a constructor always constructs an object of a particular type. However, it's quite a common pattern to do this using a factory function, perhaps like this:

```
class Base
{
public:
  static std::unique_ptr<Base> create(const std::string &class_name) {
    if (class_name == "something") {
      return std::make_unique<SomeChildClass>();
    }
  }
};
```

Note that in general, polymorphism requires dynamic object allocation (or some *very* specific scenarios), hence the unique pointer as the return type.

Comment: ... in which case there's no real reason for `create` to be part of `Base`.

Comment: @melpomene It depends. There are cases where it makes no sense, and there are cases where it's the most logical place to put it. Anyway, this answer doesn't hinge on that in any way.